# Grouping points in a ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my data

```
# Groups:   pot.code [63]
   hemiparasite host  leaf.species pot.code   pot type  Metal Value
   <fct>        <fct> <fct>        <fct>    <int> <fct> <chr> <dbl>
 1 CALE         ACMI  CALE         2B           2 B     K     0.829
 2 CALE         ACMI  CALE         2C           2 C     K     0.500
 3 CALE         ACMI  CALE         4B           4 B     K     0.610
 4 CALE         ACMI  CALE         4C           4 C     K     0.538
 5 CALE         ZEMA  CALE         12B         12 B     K     0.679
 6 CALE         ZEMA  CALE         12C         12 C     K     0.382
 7 CAFO         ACMI  CAFO         41B         41 B     K     0.638
 8 CAFO         ACMI  CAFO         41C         41 C     K     0.273
 9 CAFO         ACMI  CAFO         42B         42 B     K     0.518
10 CAFO         ACMI  CAFO         42C         42 C     K     0.329
# ... with 368 more rows
```

When graphing, I'd like the "types" B and C that are in the same pot to be linked by a line, I have done this previously with group in ggplot2, and it'd worked well. However,  for some reason the line is just showing up as a straight line through all of the data. Here is my code:

```
ggplot(leaf.graph, aes(x=leaf.species, y=Value, group=pot))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(color=host, shape=type), position=position_dodge(width=0.4))+
  facet_wrap(.~Metal, scales="free", ncol=2)+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  scale_shape_discrete(name="Type", labels =c("Parasitism", "No parasitism"))+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Host", labels= c("ACMI", "ZEMA"))
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit-- I've done this before with categorical axes-  see below for an example

Data:

```
 X        K       Na        P       Mg        Ca         S         drought pot species
1 1 19103.74 230.4304 3451.667 4657.260 19184.494 11700.592 normal watering   1    CALE
2 2 21286.39 282.5610 3639.559 3259.262  7514.861  2534.621 normal watering   1    ACMI
3 3 28356.04 182.4751 3227.498 4038.457 13496.755  8017.703 normal watering   3    CALE
4 4 23747.66 232.2271 3193.174 2558.794  5526.189  2009.643 normal watering   3    ACMI
5 5 32659.69 220.5023 2108.735 3467.477 14738.200 10490.562 normal watering   7    CALE
6 6 18798.06 410.5469 4354.962 2450.054  5913.416  3071.759 normal watering   7    ACMI
  leaves root.exclusion Leaf.Mass Leaf.Area castilleja.sp treatment unique_code shoot.ht
1     NA  no parasitism     0.515        NA  C. levisecta         1         1_1     19.6
2     47  no parasitism        NA        NA  C. levisecta         1         1_1     11.3
3     NA  no parasitism     0.761        NA  C. levisecta         1         1_3     18.4
4     47  no parasitism        NA     6.968  C. levisecta         1         1_3      9.2
5     NA  no parasitism     0.509        NA  C. levisecta         1         1_7     14.4
6     41  no parasitism        NA        NA  C. levisecta         1         1_7     16.4
```

And then we have the code for the graph, in which the grouping works

```
Mg<-ggplot(courtney.CALE, aes(x=species, y=Mg, group=unique_code))+
  geom_line(color="grey")+
  geom_point(aes(color=drought))+
  facet_wrap(.~root.exclusion)+
  newtheme; Mg
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Basically everything works fine. The issue is that you have a categorical axis. Hence you get a straight line. The points are simply not on the line as you use `position_dodge`.

To achieve the desired plot my approach converts the categorical variable `leaf.species` to a numeric, i.e `CAFO = 1` and `CALE = 2` and assigns different x-values to the different `type`s. Afterwards I apply `scale_x_continuous` to get back the categories as labels. Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

leaf.graph1 <- leaf.graph %>% 
  mutate(x = as.numeric(factor(leaf.species)))
breaks <- unique(leaf.graph1$x)
labels <- unique(leaf.graph1$leaf.species)

ggplot(leaf.graph1, aes(x = ifelse(type == "B", x - 0.2, x + 0.2), y=Value, group=pot))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(color=host, shape=type))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels = labels, limits = c(.5, 2.5)) +
  facet_wrap(.~Metal, scales="free", ncol=2)+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  scale_shape_discrete(name="Type", labels =c("Parasitism", "No parasitism"))+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Host", labels= c("ACMI", "ZEMA"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately this didn't work for me; please see the edits where I provide an example in which I have the same class of axes and data as well as class of grouping factor and it works. for some reason your solution did not give me all of the species.

Comment: Hi @Skotani1. Okay now I see. The issue is not the categorical axis per se. The issue is that you want to connect points for only one category, e.g. your types A and B in `pot = 2` are both in category `CAFO`. Hence they share the same x-axis value and you got a straight line. In the data in your edit the grouping spans over the x-axis, i.e one value for category `CAFO`, one value for category `ACMI`. Hence you have different values for the x-axis and got nice lines.

Comment: Oh! I should have figured that out. Ok, thanks so much for your help @stefan. The question is how to make it work at all without changing the axes, perhaps not possible